# NetSuite Rest API to get An Items Price

Tags: rest, postman, netsuite

I am trying to use postman to get item price / price matrix. I can get item price levels if i perform a get request to: [https://{{accountid}}.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/itemgroup/{{item_number}}?expandSubResources=true](https://%7B%7Baccountid%7D%7D.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/itemgroup/%7B%7Bitem_number%7D%7D?expandSubResources=true)

But it won't provide the item prices for each level, only the name of the levels. strangely, I won't even get the price level information if i send a similar request to other product types (in my case discount and non inventory item). Does anyone one know how i can extract product pricing information from netsuite. I have tried going through the [Docs](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/APIs/REST_API_Browser/record/v1/2020.1/index.html#tag-priceLevel) but it came up with nothing.

Here is the cURL of the request made to noninventoryitems module

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://5195388-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/noninventoryitem/284/' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer {{{accesstoken}}}"' \
--header 'Cookie: NS_ROUTING_VERSION=LAGGING'
```

Comment: Please share the relevant code.

Comment: This query returns the prices for inventoryitems: https://[account].suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/inventoryitem/[id]/price?expandSubResources=true but a similar request for noninventoryitem returns "Unknown (sub-)resource (i.e., sublist, sublist line, subrecord, reference, multiselect) price in request URL." You may want to check with NetSuite support to get more information.

Answer (score 3):

You can execute a SuiteQL query.

```
POST https://{{accountid}}.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/query/v1/suiteql
Header: Prefer: transient
Body: 
{
    "q": "SELECT i.item, i.pricelevelname, i.price, c.name as currency FROM itemprice i, currency c WHERE i.currencypage = c.id and item=967"
}
```

Sample output:

```
{
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://[accountid].suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/query/v1/suiteql?limit=1000&offset=0"
        }
    ],
    "count": 2,
    "hasMore": false,
    "items": [
        {
            "links": [],
            "currency": "USD",
            "item": "967",
            "price": "100000",
            "pricelevelname": "Base Price"
        },
        {
            "links": [],
            "currency": "USD",
            "item": "967",
            "price": "100000",
            "pricelevelname": "Partner Pricing"
        }
    ],
    "offset": 0,
    "totalResults": 2
}
```

The record and field IDs are in the Analytics Browser: https://[accountid].app.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2020_1/analytics/record/itemPrice.html.